# Translate a screen ID into it's sitemap screen title

Tags: acumatica

I am looking for an Acumatica framework call that gives me a given screen's sitemap title name based on a current screen id. We have an event history page where we want to translate the created screen id into it's related sitemap title name for a better user friendly display as the standard users do not know or care about the screen ids.

Ideally we will convert this into a field attribute on a new field in our event history DAC.

For example I might have a CreatedScreenID value of "SO301000" which I want to display "Sales Orders" in our grid for that particular row. I would create a new field called CreatedScreenTitle for this purpose. I am looking for assistance on the best way to translate the ID to the Title.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Site Map provider in the framework that is storing the complete mapping in cache (and thus you will not need to query the DB every time.)

If you have the site map ID, you wish to query, you could get the title like that:

```
var title = screenID;
var siteMapNode = PXSiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeByScreenID(screenID);
if (siteMapNode != null)
{
   title = siteMapNode.Title;
}
```

In your case, writing a custom attribute to display the value might be the best idea:

```
public class SiteMapTitleAttribute : PXStringAttribute,
                                     IPXFieldSelectingSubscriber
{
    private Type _SiteMapScreenID;
    public SiteMapTitleAttribute(Type siteMapScreenID) : base(50)
    {
        _SiteMapScreenID = siteMapScreenID;
    }

    public override void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;

        string screenID = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _SiteMapScreenID.Name) as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(screenID))
        {
            var siteMapNode = PXSiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeByScreenID(screenID);
            if (siteMapNode != null)
            {
                e.ReturnValue = siteMapNode.Title;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
public abstract class createdScreenTitle : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
[SiteMapTitle(typeof(createdByScreenID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Created Screen", Visible = true, Enabled = false)]
public virtual String CreatedScreenTitle { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Even includes the attribute i will need to create for our dac/grid - Thanks Philippe

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a framework call but you could always do it from a BQL Query.  Either joined into another query or on it's own.

If you do it on it's own, something like this would work

```
PX.SM.SiteMap sitemap = PXSelect<PX.SM.SiteMap, Where<PX.SM.SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SM.SiteMap.screenID>>>>.Select(this, sitemapid);
if (sitemap != null && sitemap.Title != null)
{
    mytitle = sitemap.Title;
}
```

You could always call this from your grid select method too

Something Like this

```
PXSelect<MyGrid> GridResults;
protected virtual IEnumerable gridResults()
{
    [....MY BASE SELECT HERE....]
    foreach......
    {
       MyGrid gridrow = new MyGrid();
       [STUFF]
       PX.SM.SiteMap sitemap = PXSelect<PX.SM.SiteMap, Where<PX.SM.SiteMap.screenID, Equal<Required<PX.SM.SiteMap.screenID>>>>.Select(this, sitemapid);
       if (sitemap != null && sitemap.Title != null)
       {
            gridrow.SiteMapTitle = sitemap.Title;
       }
       yield return gridrow
     }
}
```

The other option would be to add a selector to your field.  Something like this:

```
[PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search3<SiteMap.screenID,
OrderBy<Asc<SiteMap.screenID>>>), typeof(SiteMap.screenID), typeof(SiteMap.title),
DescriptionField = typeof(SiteMap.title))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Created By")]
public virtual void MyDAC_SiteMapTitle_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{}
```

Then change the display type in the grid to "Text"

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="SiteMapTitle" Width="200px" DisplayMode="Text">
```

Comment: Jeff - While your answer should work to answer the question i found Philippe's answer to be the better solution of the two answers. Thank you for the quick reply and support.